# NAntContrib/NAnt mkiisdir fails on IIS 7.0 / windows 2008

Tags: iis-7, permissions, nant

I'm trying to use NAnt/NAntContrib build script to build a web application on Windows 2008 (IIS 7.0).

In the build file, there is mkiisdir task, which fails with:

[mkiisdir] The webservice at 'localhost' does not exist or is not reachable.

All the documents/posts I found so far (non for w2k8, only Vista) say to install IIS 6 Compatibility services (all of them, including scripting tools, etc.) So I did, but it still throws this error.

Any idea what else need to be changes, so NAnt be able to create/delete virtual directories on IIS 7.0?

EDIT: New data - when I log in as local administrator to this server, the nant task succeeds, but it fails when I log in as a domain admin. I have added the domain admins group in the local Administrators group, but it still fails. Any idea what other permissions I need to check/change in order to make my domain admin user to be able to execute this task? I can create manually virtual folders without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question - I have isolated the part of the code in NantContrib which was causing the problem, and made a sample application to test.

I have posted this as a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263552/directoryentrynativeobject-throws-access-denied-for-a-user-in-administrators-gr), and there is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263552/directoryentrynativeobject-throws-access-denied-for-a-user-in-administrators-gr#263784) as well.

Cheers

Comment: Have you found this to work when it's not localhost? Meaning the machine your targeting mkiisdir with is not the one running the NAnt process?

Comment: But i am afraid to say it is not working for me when i have tried for remote server. Can you please provide any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 4):

In order to get iis nantcontrib tasks to work you need to install IIS6 Management Compatibility Tools. Here is the blog describing how to do it in Vista:

http://thoughtworker.in/2008/01/15/nant-the-webservice-at-localhost-does-not-exist-or-is-not-reachable/

Here is a screenshot of how to do it in Windows Server 2008:

[alt text http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/699/iis6tools.png](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/699/iis6tools.png)

Comment: Actually I did it (it's written in the question itself). There was additional problem, and the solution is in my answer. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Oh yeah you did, i must have skimmed the OP poorly :))