# DirectoryEntry.NativeObject throws access denied for a user in Administrators group in windows 2008

Tags: .net, permissions, windows-server-2008, directoryservices, administrator

I have a local user, which is member of Administrators local group.

When I run this code:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace nanttest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC"))
            {
                object absobject = entry.NativeObject;
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", entry.Name);
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I receive:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80070005): Access is denied.
>
> at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject()
>   at nanttest.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   c:\Work\nanttest\nanttest\Program.cs:line
>   20

If I run this code while logged in as Administrator, it works OK.

Also, this code fails if I run it logged in as a DomainAdmin user. I have added MYDOMAIN\DomainAdmins and MYDOMAIN\mydomainuser as members of local Administrators group.

What other permissions should I add for these users, so they can run this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question, so others can find a solution:

The problem is with the default UAC settings in Windows 2008. Even if a user is in the Administrators group, he/she still needs elevated privileges to run some operations (the one above appears to be among them).

So, solution 1 - run the application using "Run as administrator", or start it from a command prompt, which was started with that option.

Solution 2: Disable UAC for administrators group - I have used method #3 from [this article](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_uac_in_windows_vista.htm) (group policy changes). Remember to reboot the server after these changes.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at that problem and was seriously wondering what the hell was wrong.