# access denied on DirectoryEntry bind

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, iis

Can you please help

I get `"access denied"` on `DirectoryEntry` bind

Can you please help?

I'm no my windows 7 pro on my pc and am using the local iis 7.5 version.

And I do not understand what this answer means
[DirectoryEntry.NativeObject throws access denied for a user in Administrators group in windows 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263552/directoryentry-nativeobject-throws-access-denied-for-a-user-in-administrators-gr)

solution 1: run as admin does not work.

I have three sites on my iis server `local:2001/` `local:2002/` `local:2003/`  there will be more but for now this is a test

In the code behind of `local:2001/` I'm trying to get the folder path of for example

`local:2003/` but all I have is its port number  but I get I get `"access denied"` on `DirectoryEntry` bind

Comment: Some more details would be nice to answer the question.

Comment: _run as admin does not work_ - what runs as admin?  VS or your AppPool?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access or write to a folder outside the scope of your website, then in under IIS -> AppPools find your appPool and change the identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService.

this should solve your issues.

**FYI** To change the identity you need to look in the Advanced Settings.

but without further details we are only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Read these articles in regards to apppoolidentity vs network service
http://blogs.iis.net/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/10/02/tip-98-did-you-know-the-default-application-pool-identity-in-iis-7-5-windows-7-changed-from-networkservice-to-apppoolidentity.aspx 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/02/13/goodbye-network-service.aspx